# angular add property to model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular service that returns a list of items from the database.

I display those items through an ng-repeat.  I'd like to hide/show each one of them using the ng-show.

### Is it a good practice to add a "display" property directly on my items to show or hide them in the UI?

Edit: If someone could point me to an article explaining that orientation  (can't seem to find any).

Comment: Why would you add `display`when you're already using `ng-show`?

Comment: it's certainly easiest to add a property as needed...especially if the data is read only. depends on if you need to return that data to server also, or if you need storage persistence. A filter would be more efficient than `ng-show` though

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is the right choice. It enables your model to control how items are viewed according to a separately controlled logic. This makes your application scalabale too.

A filter is a better choice in further modeling your logic.

Comment: about doing it through expressions in the view what do you mean exactly?  Could you give me a brief example please?

Comment: I think I must correct myself there. What I meant was scope variable which were never referenced in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other answers, filter is the better choice for your case. Add a property display and then filter based on that property.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in dataFromServer |  filter:{ display: true }">
  {{item.name}}
  </div>
```

I have used [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to create a new property for each object

https://jsfiddle.net/k8u3c8t7/